# Angularjs ng-repeat index 3

Tags: angularjs

i have a code

```
  $scope.filteredItems =  [];
  $scope.itemsPerPage  =  10;
  $scope.itemdata    =  [];
  $scope.currentPage   =  1;
  $scope.max = 5;
  $scope.data_berita = function () {
$http.get('manajemen_data/berita/get_data').then(function(res)
{
  $scope.itemdata =  res.data;
  $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
  $scope.entryLimit = 10; //max no of items to display in a page
  $scope.filteredItems = $scope.itemdata.length; //Initially for no filter
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.itemdata.length;
});
```

}

Her problem is that I display data in a table at the limit of 10 automatic $ index + 1 value 1-10 data. when I moved the page using pagination suppose to page 2 $ index + 1 I am one another how to be 11 when he moved his page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `$index` to `($scope.itemsPerPage * $scope.currentPage)+1`

Example. if you want to display page 2, then (10 * 1)+1=11